# Age of Empires 2- multiplayer game economy score too high. suspicious to cheating

Tags: cheats, age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

I'm playing Age of empires with my friends, and I have a question if one of them cheating - the Red player, who also won. He always uses Persian units and build lots of elephant units.

At the end of game, when I was checking scores, I found something interesting, which made me think he was cheating.

Although we did not check Allow Cheats, his economy score is too high as shown in the first picture; the score components are in the second.

[image: Economy score]
[image: Components of economy score]

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by economy score, since there are many separate scores as part of economy but no total score. I'm also unsure who you are accusing of cheating (though I'm guessing it's Red from your last line), and how this score shows that he is cheating.

Comment: Yes, I think Red is cheating.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to clarify what the economy score is and how a high economy score suggests that Red is cheating? It would help people to answer this question; the question is unclear to me.

Comment: @MBorg I've edited picture. I've sent wrong one. In this picture as you might see, the difference between red (team 1) and green and yellow (team 2) is too high, and made me to think how it could be

Comment: This picture helps. I actually think it's helpful to include both - the first has the economy score, and the second has its components to give more info about the economy score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think he's cheating. The first reason is that Allow Cheats was not checked. The second is that a high economy score does not seem like sufficient grounds with which to accuse someone of cheating. [Economy score = 10% of all resources (spent or unused) + 20% of resource value of surviving units and buildings except for Castles and Wonders.](https://ageofempires.fandom.com/wiki/Score#:%7E:text=Age%20of%20Empires%20II,-In%20Age%20of&text=The%20economy%20score%20is%2010,(except%20Castles%20and%20Wonders).) A high economy score is more likely to be due to legal in-game means. Reasons including:

- Your opponent gathering more resources by having more resource gathering units. Given the high components of food and trade, it is likely that he had more villagers and/or fishing boats for food and more trade carts or trade cogs to generate trade profit (or made the trade carts travel to markets separated by greater distances). This contributes ot the 10% of all resources component of the economy score equation.
- If he won the game, he likely has more surviving units and buildings. This contributes to the 20% part of the economy score equation.

This somewhat also fits in with him using many elephants. These units require a high amount of resources, food particularly, and he would have thus placed a greater emphasis on collecting food. Elephants are strong units, and he can get away with using smaller army sizes due to their strength, as opposed to non-Persian teams which cannot access elephants and must thus compensate with a larger number of weaker units. Given a limited population limit (the standard being 75), with a smaller army, he can afford to have more units dedicated to gathering resources such as villagers, fishing boats and trade carts. This would have a greater impact over a long match, which gives more time to produce elephants and for resource-gathering units to produce resources. This match was indeed long being nearly 3 hours long.

Comment: Yes, match was so frustrating and map was 6 player sized instead of 4 players, and also  population was 200. Any suggestion to choose which civilization to defeat large army of elephants? I chose Mongols and don't want to create all my units Pikeman. Any other units suggestions?

Comment: Here's a good overview for War Elephants and how to beat them: https://ageofempires.fandom.com/wiki/War_Elephant_(Age_of_Empires_II). Btw your comment and its question doesn't really relate to your question or my answer. In the future, it'd be better to create a new question for this, but only after trying to find the answer yourself (for example, Google searching and checking wiki pages)

Comment: You can easily beat mass war elephants with mass monks. Build 20 monks, give them important upgrades like fervor, sanctity and block printing and convert his elephants. War elephants are too slow to escape or attack the monks.
Pikes are not very strong against war elephants,you'd have to build tons of them. Halbs do way better, but you also need to mass them. As Mongols you don't get halbs however.
What you DO get with Mongols is drill. So you can also go for mass onagers and outmaneuver his elephants. Onagers do quite well against them,if the elephants don't get close (drill prevents that).